# Ошибка Received unexpected end-of-file from SFTP server

Tags: linux, ssh, sftp, openssh

При попытке подключиться к серверу openssh по протоколу SFTP получаю сообщение об ошибке:

> Received unexpected end-of-file from SFTP server

С чем это может быть связано?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Данная ошибка означает, что вы успешно авторизовались на сервере SSH, но по какой-то причине не смогли получить доступ к подсистеме SFTP. То есть, SSH на удалённом сервере работает корректно, а SFTP - нет.

Самая элементарная причина, почему это может происходить - [неверное указание пути к файлу подсистемы SFTP](https://web.archive.org/web/20160701203647/http://superuser.com:80/questions/937424/cant-connect-to-sftp-received-unexpected-end-of-file-from-sftp-server) (По-умолчанию: `/usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server`) или его недоступность для сервера openssh. Убедитесь, что путь к файлу подсистемы SFTP  в конфиге SSH (`/etc/ssh/sshd_config`) прописан верно. Строка для дефолтного пути к выглядит, например, так:

```
Subsystem sftp /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server
```

Затем убедитесь, что пользователь, от имени которого запускается сервер SSH, имеет права для исполнения файла подсистемы SFTP. После внесения изменений в файл sshd_config, - если таковые потребовались, - не забудьте перезапустить SSH сервер, для вступления изменений в силу.

Если подсистема SFTP доступна, а ошибка всё равно есть, или, более того, внезапно возникла на работавшем до этого сервере, - значит к подсистеме вас не пускает сам сервер SSH. Это может произойти, если система требует совершить некое действие непосредственно в ходе подключения по SSH, - чаще всего это бывает принудительная смена пароля. В этом случае вам надо подключиться к системе по SSH и выполнить требуемое действие, после чего SFTP снова станет доступен.

Comment: ссылка протухла вроде :(

Comment: @Andrew Ага, заменил на архивную, теперь можно посмотреть. Вопрос с кучей просмотров из поисковиков внезапно удалили через год после публикации, потому что кто-то вдруг решил, что он не соответствует правилам сайта. Вообщем, всё как на ruSO.)

Comment: да, теперь работает, спасибо :)